# Firefox hangs and hard-disk becomes unresponsive

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, firefox

I have been using the system from 7:00 AM. It is now 5:18 PM. My system has been hanging almost the entire day. I can only blame Firefox for this.

My system is a Intel Pentium Dual Core (G2010) at 2.8 GHz and I run Visual Studio 2013 without any problems.

**Screenshots**

*Click for a larger view.*

[image: a]

[image: b]

Comment: Do the problem persists if you disable all the Firefox add-ons?

Comment: I have a lot of plugin. Firebug is one which used much memory. In the evening I delete the user profile and fiefox create new for me. After some minutes same problem happen again.

Answer (score 2):

## Suggestions

- See if it happens in Safe Mode https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode
- Defrag
- Exclude Firefox %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox from your Antivirus scan folders
- Place Firefox in a RAM Drive http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software or use RamCache http://www.romexsoftware.com/en-us/fancy-cache/
- Clear cache and other temporary files in Firefox
- The "block reported ..." toggles in Edit -> Preferences -> Security if unchecked could reduce some disk activity. The block reported web forgeries/attack sites feature does a lot of reading and writing to some sqlite files on the disk. (http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=294774)